Reduction from Hamiltonian Cycle to 3-SAT
I'm able to find many sources online describing the reduction from 3-SAT to Hamiltonian Cycle, which are both NP-complete problems. As such, I know that there must exist a reduction in the opposite direction, and I've been told that this has been defined, but I can't find it anywhere.
I tried searching the web rather thoroughly, but I don't have access to many textbooks/books on this subject so I'm reaching a dead end. Does anyone know if this reduction has actually been defined?

This question might be better received at CS Theory Stackexchange

It's pretty easy to reduce arbitrary combinatorial logic to 3-SAT, and pretty easy to reduce any bounded computation to proportionally-sized combinatorial logic, so if you can write a P-time program to check Hamiltonian cycle, which you can by definition of NP, then there's a P-time reduction to 3-SAT.  No need to do this for every problem.  See Cook-Levin theorem.

I found a bunch of descriptions reducing HC to plain old SAT, which is not 3-SAT, but that doesn't matter because you can split large clauses into clauses with at most 3 literals by introducing some linking variable.
